# Continuous function bounded in $X$

Tags: real-analysis

If every continuous  function on $X\subseteq\Bbb R$ is bounded then $X$ is compact. Is the easiest way to prove this is to show that $X$ is bounded and closed?

Comment: What is $X?\\  $

Comment: Thats the question of a Real analysis book worked in $\mathbb{R}$ i think that X is a subset of R

Comment: Well then yes then, you want to show $X$ is bounded and closed.

Comment: to show it is bounded, take $f(x)=x$.

Comment: I edited into the question that $X\subseteq \Bbb R$ based on your comment @COSTAPHY.

Answer (score 5):

It is bounded since $f(x)=x$ is bounded. It is closed since if $x_0\in\bar X$ and not in $X$ then $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-x_0}$ is not bounded.